# React - get request is getting the correct object but when read into react component the value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a practice problem and when I console log the response body of my get request it shows that I am fetching the correct object but when I console log the object in the component I am calling the get request in the value reads as undefined.

This is my component

```
const ReservationPage = () => {
  const [reservations, setReservations] = useState([]);
  const [apiError, setApiError] = useState();
  const [roomTypes, setRoomTypes] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllReservations(setReservations);
    getAllRoomTypes(setRoomTypes);
    console.log(roomTypes);
    console.log(reservations);
    const reservationsWithNames = [];
    reservations.forEach((reservation) => {
      console.log(reservation);
      const newEntry = {
        id: reservation.id,
        guestEmail: reservation.guestEmail,
        roomType: roomTypes[reservation.roomTypeId - 1].name,
        checkInDate: reservation.checkInDate,
        numberOfNights: reservation.numberOfNights,
        totalCost: roomTypes[reservation.roomTypeId - 1].rate * reservation.numberOfNights
      };
      reservationsWithNames.splice(0, newEntry);
    });
    console.log(reservationsWithNames);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.pageContainer}>
      {apiError
        && <p className={styles.errMsg} name="errMsg" data-testid="errMsg">{Constants.API_ERROR}</p>}
      <div>
        <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
          <h1 className={styles.title}>Maintenance</h1>
          <NavLink to="/reservations/create">
            <button
              type="button"
              name="createButton"
              data-testid="createButton"
              className={styles.createButton}
            >
              Create Reservation
            </button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.pageBody}>
          <table className={styles.table}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Guest Email</th>
                <th>Room Type</th>
                <th>Check In Date</th>
                <th>Number of Nights</th>
                <th>Total Cost</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {reservations.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).map((reservation) => (
                <tr key={reservation.id} data-testid="reservation">
                  <td>
                    <NavLink className="test-btn-reserve" to="/reservations">
                      <Button data-testd="button" className={styles.btn}>
                        <EditIcon />
                      </Button>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="test-btn-reserve" to="/reservations">
                      <Button data-testd="button" className={styles.btn}>
                        <DeleteIcon />
                      </Button>
                    </NavLink>
                  </td>
                  <td>{reservation.id}</td>
                  <td>{reservation.guestEmail}</td>
                  <td>{}</td>
                  <td>{reservation.checkInDate}</td>
                  <td>{reservation.numberOfNights}</td>
                  <td>{}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and these are my requests

```
export const getAllReservations = async (setReservations) => {
  await HttpHelper('/reservations', 'GET')
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error(Constants.API_ERROR);
    })
    .then((body) => {
      console.log(body);
      setReservations(body);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('here');
    });
};

export const getAllRoomTypes = async (setRoomType) => {
  await HttpHelper('/room-types', 'GET')
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error(Constants.API_ERROR);
    })
    .then((body) => {
      console.log(body);
      setRoomType(body);
    })
    .catch(() => {
    });
};
```

[finally this is the result I get on run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiGDe.png)

fixed code shout out to sandeep.kgp and Satyam Saurabh for the assist

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { getAllRoomTypes, getAllReservations } from './ReservationService';
import styles from './Reservations.module.css';
import Constants from '../../utils/constants';

const ReservationPage = () => {
  const [reservations, setReservations] = useState([]);
  const [apiError, setApiError] = useState();
  const [roomTypes, setRoomTypes] = useState();
  const [reservationsWithNames, setReservationsWithNames] = useState([]);

  const getName = (reservation) => {
    const roomName = roomTypes[reservation.roomTypeId - 1].name;
    console.log(roomName);
    return roomName;
  };

  const getTotalCost = (reservation) => {
    const totalCost = roomTypes[reservation.roomTypeId - 1].rate * reservation.numberOfNights;
    console.log(totalCost);
    return totalCost;
  };

  useEffect(async () => {
    await getAllReservations(setReservations).then(console.log(reservations));
    await getAllRoomTypes(setRoomTypes).then(console.log(roomTypes));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.pageContainer}>
      {apiError
        && <p className={styles.errMsg} name="errMsg" data-testid="errMsg">{Constants.API_ERROR}</p>}
      <div>
        <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
          <h1 className={styles.title}>Maintenance</h1>
          <NavLink to="/reservations/create">
            <button
              type="button"
              name="createButton"
              data-testid="createButton"
              className={styles.createButton}
            >
              Create Reservation
            </button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.pageBody}>
          <table className={styles.table}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Guest Email</th>
                <th>Room Type</th>
                <th>Check In Date</th>
                <th>Number of Nights</th>
                <th>Total Cost</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {roomTypes !== undefined
              && reservations.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).map((reservation) => (
                <tr key={reservation.id} data-testid="reservation">
                  <td>
                    <NavLink className="test-btn-reserve" to="/reservations">
                      <Button data-testd="button" className={styles.btn}>
                        <EditIcon />
                      </Button>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="test-btn-reserve" to="/reservations">
                      <Button data-testd="button" className={styles.btn}>
                        <DeleteIcon />
                      </Button>
                    </NavLink>
                  </td>
                  <td>{reservation.id}</td>
                  <td>{reservation.guestEmail}</td>
                  <td>{getName(reservation)}</td>
                  <td>{reservation.checkInDate}</td>
                  <td>{reservation.numberOfNights}</td>
                  <td>{getTotalCost(reservation)}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ReservationPage;
```

Comment: Have you tried returning the result of the GET request and then setting the state like this: `setReservations( getAllReservations() )` and `setRoomType( getAllRoomTypes() )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect is synchronous, hence before `getAllRoomTypes` calls `setRoomTypes`, your console.log is fired before your state is changed and because the `roomTypes` is initialized as `undefined`, you get `undefined` in console. Either use `async await` or put business logic in another effect which runs when `roomTypes` or `reservations` change

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should do something like @sandeep.kgp said and also you can put some conditions to render the object like,

```
(reservation !== undefined && reservation.key)
```